# why is mvvm not mvmv or vvmm

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

Why is MVVM which stands for Model - View - View Model not MVMV for Model - View Model - View or VVMM for View - View Model - Model

Since the information goes from the view to the view model till the model or the other way, isn't MVVM a wrong initialism?

Comment: Iformation flow is not always leading for naming things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

M-V-VM emphasizes the relationship to M-V-C, the architecture that MVVM derives from. This relationship was the first sentence written to introduce MVVM in 2005.

[Introduction to Model/View/ViewModel pattern for building WPF apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johngossman/2005/10/08/introduction-to-modelviewviewmodel-pattern-for-building-wpf-apps/)

> Model/View/ViewModel is a variation of Model/View/Controller (MVC) that is tailored for modern UI development platforms...

Since ViewModel replaces the Controller from MVC, it takes the same position in its respective acronym.